# My opaque illustration saved file turns partially transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I made this picture of isometric sand castle that uses gradient and when I save this image, the saved image, irrespective of the format, is transparent in some areas. There is a hue of some sort. The entire image is not this way only parts of it. The image is opaque and not intended to be transparent at all, I have used transparency on the gradients, if that means anything. There is no significant difference I can find on objects that appear as they should and objects that have become transparent. Oh and the objects all have their outlines, there is just no fill appearing.

[image: https://s16.postimg.org/mnxq12ggl/Untitled.png]

[image: https://s21.postimg.org/4i1k5mzpz/home.png]

Comment: Does the preview in Illustrator change much if you enable "overprint Preview *(View -> Overprint Preview)*? What about if you select *View -> Show Transparency Grid*? You've got something odd going on with the file, but it's hard to tell from the info posted so far. Can you upload a copy of it somewhere?

Comment: maybe some of your objects are locked, in a template layer or something else. We can't answer without looking at your file, so I'm voting to close as off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra layer under all your artwork layers which is completely opaque and visible. Alternatively you can store your image in a jpeg format. Jpeg images don't have any transparency.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the "overprint preview" (turned off) - you'll probably see the same thing as you get as an output. If so, to solve the issue, you should set the gradient as a "multiply" instead of "overprint" (that way you'll see both gradients and the solids bellow).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'Flatten transparency' option? Gradients are tricky in general btw. If you don't require the scalability of vectors, you can try 'Rasterize' option.

Edit: I had encountered similar error some other times, once it turned out my PC couldn't render it properly because my free RAM was very limited. I shut down all other programs & I succeeded saving it using PDF X:4XXX (cannot remember the actual format) as I was told by my printer rep that would be the best option when everything goes awry.